# pyodbc returning ® as?

Tags: python, unicode, windows-xp, pyodbc

on oracle db table, i have a ® character with some data

pyodbc executing the same query from WinXP 32bit and Win7 64bit gives different results

Dumping the data to a file gives output as:

Winxp : data with ?  # ® is replaced with ?

Win7 : data with ®  # Proper data

Any idea, what is the issue with WinXP,

Query code below:

```
def dbquery(dbipaddr,dbname,pwd,sid,port,querystr):
    try:
        import cx_Oracle
        conn_str=dbname+"/"+pwd+"@"+dbipaddr+":"+port+"/"+sid
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
        cur=conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(querystr)
        queryRes = cur.fetchone()
        tmp = []
        res = []

        while queryRes:
            for res in queryRes: 
                try:
                    tmp = res.read()
                except:
                   tmp = res
                tmp.append(tmp)  
            res.append(tuple(tmp))
            queryRes = cur.fetchone()
            tmp = []
        conn.close()

    except Exception, ex:
        print ex.message
        return []

    return res
```

Comment: How are you dumping the data to a file? This has nothing to do with Windows XP

Comment: I have tried dumping it using various methods, in text format, binary write to file and also using codec file open but all give the same result

Comment: I mean you need to show the code

Comment: @Esailija: added the query code

Comment: Well for this, you are not specifying connection encoding. You can do `os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'` to specify UTF-8. But I was looking for the code that dumps the data to a file as well.

Comment: file dump code is just opening a file in write mode and iterating over result and file.write.. nothing special.. will try os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'

Comment: well you can't simply just write to a file, you need to choose an encoding or the encoding will be chosen for you. It seems the encoding chosen for you in the WinXP case wasn't one that supports the `®` character. But this can be fixed when you yourself specify explicitly an encoding that supports it, such as `'cp1252'`

Comment: i had also tried using `import codecs` , 
`file = codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8")` but got the same result

Comment: Ok, keep using that. That means it was `?` before even writing to a file.

Comment: @Esailija: thanks for suggesting `os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'` it is giving proper ® now on winXP, thanks a lot :) , add it in the answer will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are 2 possible points of failure here, database connection encoding and file encoding when dumping to a file. Both
need to be specified, otherwise you are at the mercy of default encodings that will vary between platforms and might not be what you want to use.

To specify the connection encoding for database, do

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

To specify the file encoding do

```
file = codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8")
```

As you had already done, even if it didn't work at first it was the correct thing to do